# Putting two different entries under same label in a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, legend

I have plotted a graph with different data sets and trend lines. I was wondering if it was possible to have two different entries under the same label without the label appearing twice in the legend:

```
ax.plot(JD_inc, mag_inc, 'x', label = "Increasing Magnitude")
ax.plot(JD_dec, mag_dec, 'x', color = "forestgreen", label = "Decreasing Magnitude")

ax.plot(new_x_inc, new_y_inc, color = "orange", label = "Increasing Magnitude")
ax.plot(new_x_dec, new_y_dec, color = "crimson", label = "Decreasing Magnitude")


ax.errorbar(our_jul_day, our_mag, yerr = our_err, fmt = "x", color = "black", zorder = 10, label = "Our Data")

plt.legend()
```

is it also possible to remove the error bar from the "our data" label?

Here is an image of my current graph:
[image]

So, for example, is it possible to get the orange line and the blue point to essentially over lap in the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `HandlerTuple` example given in this [link](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html), the following should work in your case:

```
jd_inc_data, = ax.plot(JD_inc, mag_inc, 'x', label = "Increasing Magnitude")
new_x_inc_data, = ax.plot(new_x_inc, new_y_inc, color = "orange", label = "Increasing Magnitude")

plt.legend([(jd_inc_data, new_x_inc_data)], ["Increasing Magnitude"])
```

Comment: this has worked thank you, but when I try and replicate it for he dec_data I get the error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'

Comment: OK no worries, I had missed the comma after the variable name. Thank you!